# Loading Animation and grayed-out background not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to have a loading animation with grayed-out background upon clicking TestLoading button. But I can't get it right. The loading gif is slightly in the left side but I want it in the center. Also grayed-out background is not working.

Here's my css:

```
.divLoader {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(67, 71, 75);
  z-index: 30001;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.divLoaderContent {
  position: absolute;
  color: White;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

In my view, I have this:

```
<!--LOADER  -->
<div id="divProcessing" class="divLoader">
  <p class="divLoaderContent"><img src="~/Content/image/blocks.gif"></p>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#btnRoster1').click(function(e) {
  $("#divProcessing").show();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is revised version of css:

```
.divLoader{
  display: none;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(67, 71, 75, 0.8); 
  z-index: 30001; 
}

.divLoaderContent{
    position: absolute; 
    color: White; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);    
}
```

**And don't use p tag for img container. Use div instead**

Comment: still not working Shuvo, i've tried the code that you've provided and the result is the same with my code.

Comment: .divLoader {
      position: absolute; 
    }

can you try it?

Comment: Still not working. Actually i'm using this template : https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/ does it affects the loading animation to get not working correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project so that I could check the real scenario? It could be nesting problem too. Like your parent container might be not fully expanded

Answer (score 1):

To animate `.show()` use

```
$('#btnRoster1').click(function(e) {
  $("#divProcessing").show(800);
});
```

where 800 is 0.8 sec.

To align the gif you can use flex and get rid of absolute positioning:

```
.divLoaderContent {
  color: White;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Also not working, nothing happens. my loading gif is still in the left side.

Comment: @HudasIskaryote try to add 100% width to `.divLoaderContent`

Answer (score 1):

Moving elements (especially img tags) with top/left based on percentages can get messy because it depends on the img size. I recommend using flex with this approach. The `justify-content` will center the children horizontally and `align-items` will center vertically when `display` is `flex`

```
.divLoader {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(67, 71, 75);
  z-index: 30001;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Then have your js just modify display in css to flex when you want it to show, then `display: none` when you want it to hide;

```
$('#btnRoster1').click(function(e) {
  $("#divProcessing").css('display', 'flex');
});
```

Fiddle below (has a timeout after 3 seconds to simulate something loading) I took out the unnecessary `<p>` tag as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/Garrito/vh2ttmu9/35/

Comment: Hi Garrito, thanks but i can't get it work. I've almost stuck on this for almost 5 hours. I'm using this bootstrap template: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/ you think there's something  on this template that makes my loader not properly working?

Comment: @HudasIskaryote If you're using bootstrap, I may suggest using a modal for loading spinner. It can center, gray out the background, etc. and has a pretty simple show/hide procedure. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/
It's hard to say if that template is causing the issue without seeing your code but there are some css overrides in there that could be the issue

Comment: i've tried using modal for loading but when i can click LoadRoster button, the modal is not showing, but when i assign Add new user button (on the side panel) to show the modal, the modal is showing. It seems like there is something wrong in the main body content that keep the modal to not show. Here is the link of the css:
https://jsfiddle.net/n2ru5jz1/

Comment: Sorry Hudas, but just the CSS from the template you're using won't fully explain this issue. Without snippets of your actual html/js/css related to your question, it makes it difficult to troubleshoot the underlying issue. If it's proprietary and you can't share, I understand. I suggest inspecting the modal that does work and mimic it's html and css and any js that manipulates it and apply it to your problem. That template is using several bootstrap modals you can reference.